# How to define the number of times to run a circuit in Qristal SDK?

Tags: quantum-computing, qristal-sdk

I've been starting to create a quantum application using the Qristal SDK. I've gotten it running in a Docker image and successfully printed results from using a `qpp` back end with a kind of hello world count exercise (trying to see that it does in fact run the algo and return results expected in a quantum query).

What I am having trouble with is how to get this to run at scale. Do I need to continually run the application (as a quantum circuit) over time, or can I scale the qubits being emulated to account for a greater or more accurate outcome?

Here's is the circuit that I've tried.

```
my_sim.instring = '''
__qpu__ void QUANTUMPROGRAM(qreg q)
{
  OPENQASM 2.0;
  include "qelib1.inc";
  creg c[2];
  h q[0];
  cx q[0], q[1];
  measure q[1] -> c[1];
  measure q[0] -> c[0];
}
'''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a good start. The important concept here is that the circuit, even being emulated, is subject to the same challenges of coherence and noise as a physically generated qubit.

Ignoring the Qristal Emulator here, which offers a more accurate model for noise, the core SDK can be approached as a superposition state as you have displayed, but with the advantage of running multiple shots in that instance.

This would use the shot number argument in your config as follows:

```
my_sim.sn = 100
```

The number of shots you define will run on the circuit you create, and against the number of qubits you have defined as being emulated. The [updated onboarding guide](https://gitlab.com/qbau/software-and-apps/public/QBSDK) gives a full example of the kind of first program you are running.

Comment: Thank you. That sent me down the rabbit hole to better understand the role of shots and coherence time.